# PowerShell Script works in Windows 10 but not on Windows Embedded Standart

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, windows-embedded

I have the following script work in windows 10 but not on windows 7:

```
$LogTime = Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yyyy_hh-mm-ss"
$Path1= "TEST\TESTLog_$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd).txt"
$AffPBS= Get-Process "LLCService.exe" | Select-Object ProcessorAffinity
$AffLC= Get-Process "LCService.exe" | Select-Object ProcessorAffinity
$AffinityLLCFinal = "LLC  " + $AffPBS
$AffinityLCFinal = "LC   " + $AffLC
$FinalOutput = $LogTime+"  " +$AffinityLLCFinal +"     " + $AffinityLCFinal 
$FinalOutput | Out-File -Append $Path1
```

I have run the Powershell_ISE as administrator and also set Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned.

The results I'm getting on Windows 10:

```
10-09-2017_03-31-10  LLC  @{ProcessorAffinity=63}     LC   @{ProcessorAffinity=63}
```

THe results I'm getting on Windows 7:

```
10-09-2017_11-23-26  LLC       LC
```

It seems like the Get-Process isn't working on Windows Embedded Standard. Is there any other way of doing this.

Comment: Use WMIC, like `wmic process where name="explorer.exe"`

Comment: `Get-Process | Format-Table ProcessorAffinity, *` shows empty `ProcessorAffinity` for some processes on my standard _Win-8/64_.  Try `Get-Process "*LCService.exe"` and omit `.exe` extension  at all: try `Get-Process "*LCService"`. Check `$AffLC.GetType()` and `$AffPBS.GetType()`.

Comment: @JosefZ: Yes you are correct. Please put this as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Get-Process | Format-Table ProcessorAffinity, *
```

shows empty ProcessorAffinity for some processes on my standard *Windows-8/64bit* **even in elevated *PowerShell (ISE)***.

Moreover, [`Process.ProcessName` Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.processname(v=vs.110).aspx) (== `Name` *AliasProperty*) does not include the `.exe` extension:

> The `ProcessName` property holds an executable file name, such as
>   Outlook, that **does not include the `.exe` extension or the path**.
>   It is helpful for getting and manipulating all the processes that are
>   associated with the same executable file.

### Examples

PowerShell_ISE, **regular user**:

```
PS D:\PShell> (Get-Process * | 
    Select-Object Name, ProcessorAffinity) | 
        Group-Object -Property ProcessorAffinity | 
            Format-Table -AutoSize                    # merely for better readability

Count Name Group
----- ---- ----- 
   41      {@{Name=afwServ; ProcessorAffinity=}, @{Name=AppleMobileDeviceService; Proces...
   28 3    {@{Name=avgui; ProcessorAffinity=3}, @{Name=avguix; ProcessorAffinity=3}, @{N...
```

PowerShell as **administrator**:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> (Get-Process * |
>>     Select-Object Name, ProcessorAffinity) |
>>         Group-Object -Property ProcessorAffinity |
>>             Format-Table -AutoSize                    # merely for better readability

Count Name Group
----- ---- -----
   10      {@{Name=afwServ; ProcessorAffinity=}, @{Name=aswidsagenta; ProcessorAffinity...
   59 3    {@{Name=AppleMobileDeviceService; ProcessorAffinity=3}, @{Name=avgsvca; Proc...
```